# How to build a websocket HttpHandler

Tags: java, websocket

I'd like to use websockets with at HttpServer. Here is the HttpHandler I came up with ... and the corresponding EchoServer

```
public class WebSocketHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        String requestMethod = exchange.getRequestMethod();
        if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
            System.out.println("Well formed websocket Upgrade request");
            /*
             * HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
             * Upgrade: websocket
             * Connection: Upgrade
             * Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
             * ''Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
             */

            Headers responseHeaders = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
            responseHeaders.set("Upgrade", "websocket");
            responseHeaders.set("Connection", "Upgrade");
            responseHeaders.set("Sec-WebSocket-Accept", "XXXX");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(101, 0);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write("ok".getBytes());
            ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(EchoServer.class, "/echo").build();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server: non-GET websocket upgrade request....");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write("ok".getBytes());
        }

    }
}
```

The EchoServer class is:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/echo")
public class EchoServer {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    int id = 0;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        logger.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        switch (message) {
            case "quit":
                try {
                    session.close(new CloseReason(CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE, "Game ended"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                break;
        }
        id++;
        return String.format("%d:%s", id, message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }
}
```

I don't have much hope that this will work because I don't think the connection IDs are exchanged.

How would you complete this code to get a functional websocket connection?

Comment: Sooo... what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange` for WebSocket isn't going to work.

That API for that doesn't allow for a true upgraded connection.  In other words, a connection where there is no HTTP connection encoding or encapsulation (such as chunked, or gziped, etc)

Also, your protocol handling of the WebSocket upgrade isn't valid, no browser out there will find that response to be valid and continue the upgrade.

2 examples in your code.

- `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` must be provided, and be correctly calculated from the incoming request headers
- `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` must be provided, if the incoming request has one defined