# HttpServer and Websocket

Tags: websocket, httpserver

I m trying to make the com.sun.net.httpserver work with WebSocket.

I was able to do the handshake and the browser gets connected then directly disconnect.
is there anyway to make the websocket work with com.sun.net.httpserver ?
Can anyone help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Comment: Hey @Wtower, i'm kind of new in this field .. I want to connect the websocket to this https server : com.sun.net.httpserver. it has to work on websocket otherwise i'll have to re-do the whole application. if you have any suggestions that might help please send them . Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a websocket HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079015/how-to-build-a-websocket-httphandler)